# asp.net mvc5 validating list of objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I have a view for entering delivery quantities on every items in the list, and sends a list of objects back to controller. I would like to validate all textboxes on the page, and I have added annotations in the model.

The problem is, I can only validate the first row (also in the output html only the first row has validation markups). Since there are generated validations on the first row, so I don't think it's about the model. Is there a way to have generated validations in all rows? If not, what are the workarounds?

```
    @{int i = 0;}
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.eo, new { Name = "[" + i + "].eo" })
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.barcode)
                @Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].barcode", Model[i].barcode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemno)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cdesc)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.acost)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.qty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.dqty, new { htmlAttributes = new { Name = "[" + i + "].dqty", id = "[" + i + "].dqty", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("[" + i + "].dqty", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        i++;
    }
```

This is the generated html for the textbox in the first row.

```
<input Name="[0].dqty" class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field 出貨數量 must be a number." data-val-required="必須填上出貨數量" id="[0].dqty" name="item.dqty" type="text" value="10" />
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[0].dqty" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

And the second row onwards...

```
<input Name="[1].dqty" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="[1].dqty" name="item.dqty" type="text" value="7" />
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[1].dqty" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

The Model

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EorderDetailsMetaData))]
public partial class EorderDetails
{
    public string eo { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public string itemno { get; set; }
    public string cdesc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> qty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> dqty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> acost { get; set; }
    public string sdate { get; set; }
    public string edate { get; set; }
    public string shop { get; set; }
    public string sname { get; set; }
    public string saddr { get; set; }
    public string shoptel { get; set; }
    public string shopfax { get; set; }
}

public class EorderDetailsMetaData
{
    [Display(Name = "訂單編號")]
    public string eo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "電腦條碼")]
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "貨品編號")]
    public string itemno { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "貨品名稱")]
    public string cdesc { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "訂購數量")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<decimal> qty { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "出貨數量")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "必須填上出貨數量")]
    public Nullable<decimal> dqty { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "成本價")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<decimal> acost { get; set; }
    public string sdate { get; set; }
    public string edate { get; set; }
    public string shop { get; set; }
    public string sname { get; set; }
    public string saddr { get; set; }
    public string shoptel { get; set; }
    public string shopfax { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be generating the collection in a `for` loop and let the helpers generate the correct html for you. If you inspect the html you have posted in the second snippet you will see the issue (two `name` attributes!)

```
@model IList<EorderDetails>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].eo)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].barcode)
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].dqty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].dqty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
  }
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Alternatively you can create a custom `EditorTemplate` for your model

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EorderDetails.cshtml

```
@model EorderDetails
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.eo)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.barcode)
....
```

and in the main view

```
@model IList<EorderDetails>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: It works~! I know `foreach` and `i` variable is not the best practice, but I never thought it is the reason. Thank you very much Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

To omit this strange behavior, there should:

1. Define the property as Array, instead of ICollection or IList.
2. Should use for in cshtml, instead of forEach.

Have no idea why this will cause the difference. But I think it should not. And I think this is a bug should be fixed.